# how make url obfuscated

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

I want to make the images and download videos url obfuscated in wordpress so that visitors could not see the exact path of the images and videos url. I have tried short url plugin for this but it is not working.please let me know the any plugin in wordpress which I can used or Can I do it using the htaccess file ?

Comment: what's the point of this? if you're loading these images/videos in a web page, a simple view source will reveal the urls. obfuscated urls still resolve to actual resources, so you're not doing anything to prevent theft/downloading.

Comment: If you want to stop hotlinking that is a very different topic that you should probably look into. As Marc points out, obfuscated urls are worthless.

Comment: As long as a browser can load something, it's up for the user grabs. Watermark them :)

Comment: Can I do something so the user can see only relative path ?

Comment: Well, yes, as Marc suggests, there is no point in trying to mask any URL where you save your media. I can just go to Facebook or Twitter and find out that they are storing their media in content delivery websites like static.ak.fbcdn and akamaicdn and twimg. They don't bother masking anything.

Answer (score 1):

Obsfucating media URL is not useless, it has its own purpose. Here's an example:

You have a gallery/images like this:

```
http://example.com/images/gallery-001/img-001.jpg
http://example.com/images/gallery-001/img-002.jpg
http://example.com/images/gallery-001/img-003.jpg
and so on...
```

Obsfucating the urls is a good way to prevent typical non-techie audience to guessing the image urls instead of viewing them on site.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscating the media URL is possible, of course, but it's meaningless. If you don't want people to see the actual source, just download the file on your own server and replace the link(s).